# In BusyBox why the maximum packet size is limited to 32768 while maximum IP packet size can be 65535

Tags: busybox, traceroute, max-size

There is a check in busybox,the packet size should be in between 38 to 32768(32 * 1024). If the size is greater than 32768 traceroute will not be triggered.
Why this kind of limitation exists in busybox? The maximum IP Packet size can be 65535. Could you please clarify the reason for this limitation? Do we face any issues if the packet size is increased beyond 32768?

Answer (score 0):

By design, BusyBox was developed for devices/systems with limited resources (RAM, CPU) such as home routers, embedded controllers.

32k is a quite of bit of RAM for an older embedded system.

EDIT:

By looking at RFC1191 Section 3.1, the TCP MSS option description includes a note that some IP implementations may have a sign-bit bug that could be tickled by unnecessary use of such a large MSS.

Comment: Thanks Brooks for your answer.
I would like to know why this kind of limitation is present only for traceroute  and not for the ping. In ping we can very well generate till the maximum IP packet size of 65535